# Formatting Numbers to have a comma on plt.colorbar() in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to format my colorbar such the numbers are formatted with commas. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.matshow(np.array(([30000,8000],[12000,25000])))
plt.colorbar()
```

Comment: https://preinventedwheel.com/matplotlib-thousands-separator-1-step-guide/

Comment: FWIW, for a new user with 6 rep, this is an outstanding MCVE.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create and specify a [custom formatter](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

comma_fmt = FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ','))

plt.matshow(np.array(([30000,8000],[12000,25000])))
plt.colorbar(format=comma_fmt)

plt.show()
```

[image]