# Add thousands comma separator to Seaborn Heatmap

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

My question is something related to: [How to add title to Seaborn Heatmap color bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092218/how-to-add-title-to-seaborn-heatmap-color-bar/42092328)

I have the following code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'x':(1,2,3,4),'y':(1,2,3,4),'z':(1400,1500,2300,2000)})

sns.heatmap(data.pivot_table(index='y', columns='x', values='z'), 
                             cbar_kws={'label': 'colorbar title'})
```

[image]

And I would like to add thousands separator to the color bar thickers, 2'250 or 2,250 for example. How can I accomplish this?

EDIT:
I was redirected here: [Formatting Numbers to have a comma on plt.colorbar() in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230711/formatting-numbers-to-have-a-comma-on-plt-colorbar-in-python)
Indeed it makes sense, but, how do I extract that from the seaborn heatmap?

EDIT 2 - Solution:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

data = pd.DataFrame({'x':(1,2,3,4),'y':(1,2,3,4),'z':(1400,1500,2300,2000)})

comma_fmt = FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ','))

sns.heatmap(data.pivot_table(index='y', columns='x', values='z'), 
                             cbar_kws={'label': 'colorbar title','format':comma_fmt}).get_figure()
```

Comment: How could I extract the seaborn object to modify it? I was looking at docs but there is no clear way to do it

Comment: Sorry, since you already managed to get the title into the colorbar, I wouldn't have thought that it was a problem to implement the linked solution. It's simply `cbar_kws={'label': 'colorbar title', "format": comma_fmt}`, where `comma_fmt` is the one from the linked question. Next time, also use the @ notification to the people who closed the question if you want to ask further details.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks! I've updated the code for reference with the solution.